# How to play Kha'zix mid-lane?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am experiencing hard time playing Kha'zix against other mid-lane champions. What are the different ways to play him efficiently?

Comment: start w at level 1 to secure last hits and avoid taking too much minion harrass up close, cuz they really hurt early game.

Comment: @M'vy has cleaned this up, we should re-open it. Also, User58142, if this answer helped you (and you said it did) you should checkmark it as 'Accepted'. Please and Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you need to understand how Kha'zix works. He's a good assassin and a great champion to roam the map.

In lane, here's a few tips about the abilities themselves:

- Passive: gives more damage for the next attack, refreshes when you can't be seen. Try to have this active as much as possible. In mid for example, if all the enemy minions/champions are in the middle of the path, go hide behind one of the walls to the forest so you active the passive again. You should do this every time you want to engage for a poke or trade.
- Q: This does fairly high damage. If you want to engage/trade you'll use this but try to get your opponent alone, it will deal more damage.
- W: It shoots out some spikes. This is the first skill you should "power up" at level 6. If you are in the hitting area you get healed as well. It's also good to maintain your HP and allow you to stay longer in lane
- E: This will allow you to jump. Once evolved it will give you a very big distance and the CD resets on assists/kills.
- R: Allows you to go invisible for a few seconds. You can use this two times unless you evolve in which case it's 3. Also, every time you are able to level this up you'll be allowed to evolve one of your other skills.

Items:

- Simply put, there are two things you should start with: either Tear of the Goddess to allow you to have more mana to spam skills and stay in lane longer, or the Brutalizer to have more damage.
- Followed this, just do a normal mid AD build, focused on damage, and not attack speed or crit. Things like Bloodthirster, Last Whisper, Frozen Mallet etc.
- As for boots you can either go the mobility ones (insane speed) if you are planning on roaming a lot or you take the Ioninas boots of lucidity for reduced cooldown.
- Guardian Angel is also awesome.

Gameplay:

- Simply focus on being behind minions and farming if your opponent is very strong early. Else do as a normal AD Mid. Later you'll start to understand how he works as you play him. As I said before hide from enemy sight to get your passive so you'll do more damage before engaging, and try to get some E-Q-W combos on your opponent, unless it's something like an Ahri. If it is, wait for her taunt/charm to go in CD and do that. You can also spam W from a distance to try and hit her. At level 6, once you evolve your W (should be the first like I said) you will clear waves really, really fast, which will allow you to counter-jungle your enemies wraiths or roam and gank the other lanes.

This is pretty much the basics, I can't teach you from here as you need to be familiarized with the Champion it self or playing AD Mid!

Good luck!

Comment: WoW, this help so much, thank you so much. Can u tracy me how to trade with the opponent with khazix???????????????

Comment: To trade your opponent first try to land a few W's on him. If you get him with the thing around him (means he will take more damage and he is far from any minion) try to jump and Q+W him. 
Once you are sure that you can give a kill, go all in with R+E+Q+W+Ignite.

Comment: but Khazix W is nerd so it do not so much damage, r there anyway to trade without W?

Comment: W is what? Well W does quite a decent damage if you level it up first. There is another way which is poke him with jumping + Q on him after getting out of his sight.

But Khazix was hardly nerfed (on his W exactly) which is why he is not that good anymore.

By the way if my first answer answered your post click under the vote in that "check" ( V ) so that people know it has an answer

Comment: Ever since his W nerf, khazix is imo much more Q-oriented than W. not sure if tears is really a good idea any more.

Comment: Yeah, first leveling your Q combined with the passive isolation mechanic and his passive it deals huge amounts of damage.
I don't think either that getting tear is that viable anymore since it wastes a good amount of his potential.